# MAAS - CLI or API for deploy

Tags: command-line, maas

we have installed MAAS, however we are not able to find any information / documentation how to deploy ready node's through API or CLI?

We are only able to deploy node's through MAAS API.

Is there a way to automate this :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To deploy from CLI a node with hostname=maas-1.maas

```
maas maas node commission <node-uuid> # will change to commissioning and then ready
maas maas nodes acquire name=maas-1.maas # will change to allocated
maas maas node start <node-uuid> # will change to deploying and deployed
```